# How to stream Kubernetes log files to a different location using fluent-bit?

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes, log-files, fluentd

I have a requirement where I want the log files of all the Kubernetes containers stored in the location `/var/log/containers/` to be kept persistent even after a cluster restart or node issue. I have already implemented the EFK with elastic search, fluent-bit and Kibana. But now I want the log files as it is. I tried using the same fluent-bit to forward the log to a different location using the following configuration:

```
fluent-bit.conf: |
[SERVICE]
    Flush         1
    Log_Level     info
    Daemon        off
    Parsers_File  parsers.conf
    HTTP_Server   On
    HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
    HTTP_Port     2020

[INPUT]
    Name              tail
    Tag               kube.*
    Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
    Parser            docker
    DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
    Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines   On
    Refresh_Interval  10

[OUTPUT]
    Name            file
    Match           *
    Path            /logs
```

But I can't see the files getting created. Am I looking at the wrong path or are the files not getting created at all?

I am also open to using any other tools to produce the result. Could anyone please help me with the situation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the Kubernetes node's kubelet configuration to use a custom log directory. By default, Kubernetes logs to /var/log/containers. To change this, edit the kubelet configuration file (typically located at /etc/default/kubelet or /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf) and add the --log-dir flag.

```
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--log-dir=/logs #Replace /logs with your desired directory
```

After making the changes to the kubelet configuration, restart the kubelet service for the changes to take effect.

```
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

Use **Fluent Bit** to forward logs from the custom log directory to your **Elasticsearch** or **EFK stack**. Your Fluent Bit configuration file should include the necessary output settings.

```
[SERVICE]
Flush         1
Log_Level     info
Daemon        off
Parsers_File  parsers.conf
HTTP_Server   On
HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
HTTP_Port     2020

[INPUT]
Name              tail
Tag               kube.*
Path              /logs/*.log
Parser            docker
DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
Skip_Long_Lines   On
Refresh_Interval  10

[OUTPUT]
Name            es
Match           *
Host            <your_elasticsearch_host>
Port            <your_elasticsearch_port>
Index           kubernetes_logs
```

Replace **<your_elasticsearch_host>** and **<your_elasticsearch_port>** with your **Elasticsearch** server's details.

Restart Fluent Bit to apply the new configuration

```
sudo systemctl restart fluent-bit
```